# Why does typescript allow default parameters before required parameters?

Tags: function, typescript, compiler-errors, optional-parameters, default-parameters

i just noticed , that this function (using default params) doesn't cause error on compilation.

```
function buildAddress(address1 = 'N/A', address2: string) {
        displayAddress( address1 +' '+ address2);
    }
```

but this function (using optional params) does.

```
function buildAddress(address1?: string, address2: string) {
        displayAddress( address1 +' '+ address2);
    }
```

why is it so ?

i'm really surprised of this behavior, is that normal ? does it have any benefit ? is this a feature or a bug ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to use the first version without passing the first argument?

```
function buildAddress(address1: string = 'N/A', address2: string) {
    console.log(address1, address2);
}

buildAddress("address2");
```

Results in:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

If you put the default value for the 2nd parameter though:

```
function buildAddress(address1: string , address2: string = 'N/A') {
    console.log(address1, address2);
}
```

It works.

Adding default value for the first parameter only helps you in case you pass `undefined`:

```
buildAddress(undefined, "address2");
```

As it compiles to:

```
function buildAddress(address1, address2) {
    if (address1 === void 0) { address1 = 'N/A'; }
    console.log(address1, address2);
}
```

So in reality if you're doing this then the first parameter isn't optional at all, you must pass a value, and you only get the default value if you pass `undefined`.
But the compiler won't complain about the function signature because the first parameter has a value for sure, but in your 2nd function, since the first param is optional the compiler complains.

---

#### Edit

This behvior can be used to safe guard against `undefined` values, for example:

```
function buildAddress(address1 = 'N/A', address2: string) {
    displayAddress(address1 + ' ' + address2);
}

function getAddress1(): string {
    // logic here, might return undefined
}

buildAddress(getAddress1(), "address 2");
```

I'm not sure if this is by design or just a byproduct, but it's useful in certain cases.

Comment: yea i know that, but i'm really surprised of this behavior, is that normal ? does it have any benefit ? is this a feature or a bug ?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug, but I edited my answer with an example of how it's useful. You can file a bug report and see how they respond. I would like to follow on that if you do